# My internal memory(not free storage) just vanished?

Tags: rooting, root-access, internal-storage

I own a lenovo vibe c, currently running Android 5.1. The phone has an internal memory of 16 GB.

The phone ran well for about 8 months, and as my mother used it more it was not put to heavy tasks until I downloaded *Asphalt 8* and *NFS no limits.* Gradually the phone began to lag and it was about two weeks ago that the phone lagged seriously and at last my mother took it to the service centre. The guys at the centre did a factory reset (perhaps) and as a result I lost my games(). After that when my mother brought the phone back home I was stunned to see that the internal memory has dropped down to 8 GB (according to the system, see below). But however clean master shows it to be around 4GB (while before it showed the total space to be 16GB):

[image: system showing internal storage] [image: CM]

Now I'm really confused. Please help me.
Also I want to say that to play the games again without lag I decided to root my phone to install the RAMEXPANDER and swap some sdcard memory to increase the ram virtually. So I also have a question that can the rooting process take away some memory(as a side effect, in case something went wrong) ( I am new to it and so I don't know much about it)

I had swapped about 600MB memory of my internal storage and also I had noticed the problem before I installed the *RAM expander.* I am totally confused with it, while the system shows 8GB storage, other apps like Clean Master, ES File Explorer, KingRoot etc. everyone shows it to be around 4GB.

Comment: Well, the first thing you can do is remove all that Clean Master, RAM Expander, and other "speedup" or performance enhancing garbage... all they do is slow down your device and the very premise of Ram Expander of closing apps will cause nothing but problems. I am confused by your post, if your internal storage had "vanished" the phone would not function. Can you articulate the problem better? Although at this point I would recommend clearing app caches, clearing the cache partition, and as a last resort performing a factory reset.

Comment: I am confused too. I have never seen this before. I think some part of my memory just got hidden (sort of) and so the system cannot show it (correct me if I am wrong). As for RAM expander, i have tested it to get somewhat positive results.

Comment: BTW, Clean Master doesn't take into account system files, so the 4.14GB is correct if you consider the 3.86GB is for the system. Adds up to exactly 8GB, I guess I don't see the problem. It matches what the system's storage app says too. Sounds like a deeper problem (hardware/kernel or ROM issue) than your apps... Factory reset and see if it clears it, or flash back to pure stock w/o root.

Comment: But previously clean master showed the total space to be 16GB, but now it shows this. Also I want to avoid factory reset. BTW by the RAM expander I mean ROEHSOFT RAMEXPANDER (root required) that swaps some amount of ur sdcard memory and makes the system believe that the actual ram is the physical one + the virtual one. It does not close apps to boost the device.

Comment: Oh... I got it.... You lost your storage to Ram Expander, it is using it as cache space and it is not accessible to applications or regular internal storage anymore. (best guess after I looked at RE again)

Comment: Not cache space... Virtual memory..  you probably assigned 8gb to it?

Comment: @jyoti proy Or perhaps at the service centre, they opened your phone and removed the previous memory to reduce it to a new one of 8GB (⁉⁉)

Comment: @WrichikBasu A smartphone is not like a PC where you can simply plug memory banks. RAM is rather on the chip itself. So service centre at best could have "swapped" the entire device. But I rather go with what acejavelin writes, as that's the most likely cause: to create swap space, that space must be taken from somewhere. So if OP confirms having assigned 8GB swap, that perfectly matches. In that case I'd rather reduce swap to 1GB – as swap is far from being a "performance booster". Especially not in this context.

Comment: @acejavelin your guess would have been correct if I had noticed the problem after installing the RAM expander, by the problem had caught my attention before that. Also with RAM expander I swapped 600MB memory, which I later freed up.

Comment: @Izzy I had swapped about 600MB memory of my internal storage and also I had noticed the problem before I installed the RAM expander. I am totally confused with it, while the system shows 8GB storage, other apps like Clean Master, ES File Explorer, KingRoot etc. everyone shows it to be around 4GB.

Comment: There are several apps available helping you to [analyze your storage](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_storageanalysis). What also would help is using a [terminal app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_992) (or `adb shell`) and check the output of `df` (and maybe `mount`). The former should reveal how much storage is really there, and the second should confirm which storage is used. More over, our [internal-storage tag-wiki](/tags/internal-storage/info) links some useful questions with answers.